# Install and configure Oracle 12c XE/Enterprise on Centos 7

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c, ojdbc

Oracle provided descriptive documentation to deploy Oracle database/Manager/Clients. So, we have followed the link which summarise the things: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-oracle-database-12c-on-centos-7/

There are a few pain points we are facing:

1. Remote connection to oracle not happening
2. Remote oracle manager link access on port 5500
3. Details on Remote JDBC connections to Oracle 12c is not in one place and how to build the connection from JBDC

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: how to resolve the points [1-3] :
if we have a client from MAC OS X or  Centos 7.x

Comment: we have attempted few steps:
1. checked telnet access on 5500
2. connection port for 1521

Comment: Well, at least show us the error message you get, if any. How are you trying point 1, what do you mean by remote oracle manager, 'dbexpress'?

Comment: yes it was about dbexpress.

Comment: resolved for now.

Comment: unblocked the ports on firewall : `firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=1521/tcp;`
`firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=5500`
success

`firewall-cmd --reload`